# How to execute shell commands stored In a text file in raspbian?

Tags: raspbian-buster

I wrote a text file with some linux shell commands and I tried to make it executable with this

```
sudo chmod a+x filename
```

But when I am clicking the file it is opening in the text editor. While checking the properties I found it is not executable at all. How to make it executable.

Comment: There will be an option in the GUI to execute text files.  Have a look at the GUI properties and options. Perhaps try right-clicking on the text file to see options.

Comment: This is the main problem . Like kali or UBUNTU I can't find such option . I am using raspbian buister.

Comment: Which GUI?  I only use my Pis headless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean with *textfile* in the first version of your question. To run it as program it can be a source file or a script. A source file must be compiled with a compiler like `gcc` to get an executable binary program. With a script you need an interpreter.

I assume you mainly mean to execute a script. Executing it is only possible with an interpreter like bash, python, perl, awk, sed or any other known interpreter. If you want to make it executable you have to tell the operating system what interpreter it has to use. This is done with the first line in the script, a so called **shebang**. For a bash script you have to insert as first line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

For a python script it could be

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
or better
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Similar lines are needed for other interpreter.

If you have added the shebang then you must make the script executable as you already have done with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo chmod a+x filename
rpi ~$ ls -l filename
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 0 Oct 22 18:26 filename
```

Notice the three `x` in the modes. If you want to execute the script from the same directory you are in you have to prefix `./` to avoid unwanted execution:

```
rpi ~$ ./filename
```

Comment: An alternative to `./` is to add the directory with the script(s) to your PATH environment.

Comment: I was not talking about python. I am talking about linux shells. Like making a shutdown command that shutdown the PC after specified minutes and I want to make it clickable. So that I can execute that file with double click.(I am not talking about the default shutdown command)

Comment: @SohanArafat Just add the shebang `#!/bin/bash` to the script, make it executable, as both described in the answer and double click it in the GUI.

Comment: My god you over described everything. But now I get it. Thanks

Comment: The `#!/bin/bash`, even though best practice, is not required if you start from the shell. If it is missing, the GUI however will probably not execute it with `bash` as interpreter.